Die Rolle von "wenn" in einem spezifischen Satz

Wenn heute neue Wahlen wären, wenn welcher Partei gibst du deine Stimme?

Ich verstehe die Rolle von wenn im zweiten Satz nicht. Diesen Satz habe ich einer offiziellen Umfrage entnommen.

Das ist ein Fehler. Das wenn gehört dort nicht hin.

Das ist ein Fehler. Diese Version wäre korrekt:

Wenn heute Neuwahlen wären, welcher Partei würdest du dann deine Stimme geben?


Das habe ich mir auch so gedacht. Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort.
